# How to remove everything after a word

Tags: notepad++

How I can remove everything after `domain.com/`?

Example:

```
csa.domain.com/blsbls/lsads
asd.domain.com/blabla
bsa.domain.com/blsbls
```

I want to to remove everything after `domain.com/` so my result will be:

```
csa.domain.com/
asd.domain.com/
bsa.domain.com/
```

Comment: Generally, you need a program that recognizes slashes to be separators, like how spaces are separators for words.  Then, Ctrl-right arrow may jump you to the slash.  (Then it's a matter of Shift-End, then Delete.)

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to to remove everything after `domain.com/`

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `com.*$`
- Set "Replace with" to `com`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
csa.domain.com/blsbls/lsads
asd.domain.com/blabla
bsa.domain.com/blsbls
```

**After**:

```
csa.domain.com/
asd.domain.com/
bsa.domain.com/
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score -1):

If you dont have installed notepad try online text tool :

http://www.text-filter.com/tools/remove-everything-after-slash/

Comment: What question are you answering?